# 2 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, memory, program-entry-point

Can someone help me to solve this problem? 
the code: http://pastebin.com/nDG7YGk5

the full error: 
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at Stack.push(Stack.java:16)
    at hanukkah.input(hanukkah.java:42)
    at hanukkah.main(hanukkah.java:50)

I'm not using a virtual machine,
just eclipse.

Thanks.

Comment: Really? Where do you think your code is running in? In Eclipse?

Answer (score 4):

This is an infinite loop:

```
 while(n!=0)
 s.push(n);
```

The value of `n` isn't changing when you push it to the Stack. So it will never equal 0. You probably meant that to be an `if` statement (to make sure the user didn't enter 0), or to put the while loop around the scanner so that they can keep entering digits until they don't equal 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do something like:

```
int n = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
while (n != 0) {
   n = reader.nextInt();
   s.push(n);
}
```

Comment: Okay I think I got it, let me fix the infinite loop